# How can I unShow() after Spreadsheet.show(HtmlOutput)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this working very nicely :

```
var theForm = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('aForm').evaluate();
var theSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

theSpreadsheet.show(theForm);
```

When the user has submitted data I want to close "theForm".  Is there something like an unShow() or hide() method on a spreadsheet? a harikiri() method on an HtmlOutput?

Ideally, I'd like to have a reShow() command that saves the submitted data, refreshes the spreadsheet and calls show() again.

I have found no way to do these things, so I just disable the submit button. Ugh!

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE (2012/08/28) :*  I should have mentioned that I am calling back into the same code as originally opened "theForm", from the HTML form, using this call ...

```
google.script.run.recordTheForm(jsonTheForm);
```

Do I assume correctly that google.script.run.***() calls have no knowledge of any variable values set earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlService doesn't have an equivalent of app.close()... this is an oversight, not something by design, and we will fix it.

Edit: From within client-side JavaScript code (not from the server like `app.close()`, but within the HtmlService code itself) you can now call `google.script.host.closeDialog()`

Comment: Can't argue with that!  Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Call this:

```
theForm.close();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
theSpreadsheet.show(theForm);
```

Good luck,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: Thomas.  Thank you, with the insufficient info I initially provided, you pointed my in the right direction.

Comment: I found no such method HtmlOutput.close(), although there is HtmlOutput.clear().  Nevertheless, after poking around a bit, I came to the conclusion I mention in my update above; calling back into the calling memory space with google.script.run doesn't seem to be possible.  In the end, by flushing the sheet and showing a new form I have given the end users what they wanted.  They may use more memory each time, but I see no  need, or even a way, to examine what happens down that deep.

Comment: Well happy to help :)
I was just typing this presuming the HtmlOutput had a close function just like an UiApp. But clear works just fine then.
I dont know how you can reduce the memory.

Comment: I couldn't use clear() either!  Calling back to the *.gs code from js code in the browser did not get me the same memory space as launched the the HtmlOutput in the first place.

Comment: Could you post (send me) your complete code so i can see what you exactly want to do and where it goes wrong?

Comment: I do have it working.  As I said, ".. by flushing the sheet and showing a new form I have given the end users what they wanted."  I've asked a new question about the remaining issue. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12655469/1544075

Comment: Thomas, it seems that by accepting CoreyG's answer I unaccepted yours and cost you points.  Sorry, didn't know.