# What is the scope of variables available to google.script.run.myFunction()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like a little sanity check if I may.

Can Javascript code in an HtmlOutput window floated over a Google spreadsheet alter variables and call methods in the gs code that created the HtmlOutput in the first place?

I have a Google spreadsheet with a floating form created like this:

> *someCode.gs*

```
var theForm;
var theSpreadsheet;
function makeForm() {
    :
  theForm = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('aForm').evaluate();
  theSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  theSpreadsheet.show(theForm);
    :
}

function recordTheForm(jsonFormData) {
    :
  theForm.clear();
    :
}
```

Attached to a button in the HTML of "aForm.html" I have a function call back into the file "someCode.gs".

> *aForm.html*

```
  :
google.script.run.recordTheForm(jsonTheForm);
  :
```

Am I right that, even though it was instantiated from someCode.gs, the caller of recordTheForm() can have no knowledge of the contents of that originating memory space?

Is there anyway to get it? such as passing a "context" back and forth?

Comment: To pass data, did you read "Success and Failure Handlers" in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#GoogleScriptAPI

Comment: I know about them, but tried to keep my question simple, by not adding them.  Did I assume wrongly, that they have no bearing on my question?  I am passing data successfully without them.

Comment: 3 machines - Your function makeForm() runs on a google server. The code in aFrom.html runs in a browser. Your function recordTheForm runs on a different google server.  - While I am not 100%, that is how GAS looks to be setup.

Comment: eddyparkinson. This certainly is the way it looks to me to.  I'd just like to see it officially documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in GAS:

Browser button clicks and other browser events produce a call to GAS. Every call from the browser to GAS causes your GAS code to re-run, re-initializing all variables. This is a problem for global variables. Global variables need to be passed back from the Browser to your GAS code or reloaded from the Database or Script Properties.

Comment: Hey, You found it!  Thank you.  Do you have the URL for it?

Comment: Not sure where the docs state this in black and white. But I understand <widget>.getTag() and <widget>.setTag() were created to address some of the problems caused by the script restarting on every call back.